# Open Link From Alert Dialog Box Button Android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert box that pops up asking a user to help translate two buttons "Help Translate" and "Close" how do I make it so when the user clicks "Help Translate" it takes them to a website example.com.

Can this be done with alert dialog box or do I have to make a layout file with custom box

And also how do I make the "Help Translate" button left and "Close" right

[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    case R.id.action_about:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.about_text));
        builder.setNeutralButton("Close", null);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        return true;

        case R.id.action_translate:
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.translate_text));
            builder.setPositiveButton ("Help Translate", null);
            builder.setNeutralButton("Close", null);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
```

Comment: Try to implement OnClickListener for positive and negative button and do your work on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `onClickListner()` for `PositiveButton` and `NegativeButton` like

```
 builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()       {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // what ever you want to do with No option.
          builder.dismiss();
      }
    });
```

and

```
  builder.setPositiveButton("Help Translate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      builder.dismiss();
      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
      startActivity(browserIntent);
       }
    });
```

For more information [Go to](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: how about auto open to playstore?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Button with getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getButton(int)

Then you can do something like that when you click the Help Translate button :

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```